# Does TypeOrm automatically invalidate the cache?

Tags: typescript, caching, typeorm

I am working on a project which uses TypeOrm and I wanted to implement caching of database queries. Since TypeOrm supports caching directly by `QueryBuilder`.`cache` method, my code ended up looking something like this:

```
const items = this.itemsRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('item')
    .where('item.name = :name', { name })
    .cache(
        CacheKeyMaker.makeCacheKey('item', name), // generate cache key
        300000, // 5 minutes
    )
    .getMany();
```

NOTE: I used ioredis as the cache driver

What I noticed then, after an insert or an update to the database, the cached keys were removed from the db (invalidated). Does TypeOrm cache automatically invalidate queries on each table after insert/update/delete? And if so, how "intelligent" is it? Does it only invalidate keys that were affected by the update? For example, if I query items with `name="box"` and then insert an item with a different name, will the cache still be invalidated (because the cache is actually still valid in this case).

I tried to manually test how TypeOrm cache invalidation works, but it seemed it's working inconsistently. I will be grateful for any knowledge, thanks in advance!

Comment: hey there, i think the duration attribute you set in cache when you initialize typeorm will invalidate the cache.. 
also can you help me out with the ioredis configuration you have done? i am struggling with it a bit..
i have ioredis working but i cant get the typeorm config right.. how did you reuse the ioredis connection?
i am struggling coz my ioreids points to a sentinel and i am not sure sure what attributes to pass on in typeorm.